# Best way to have both php 5.2 and php 5.3 at the same time in Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, php, php5

I am using Ubuntu 12.04. I *need* (this is not an option) to have both php 5.2 and php 5.3 installed. I think I need to compile 5.2 from source and keep it in /usr/local or make checkinstall.

Is there any better way? How would you do this? Are there any official repositories with php52 for Ubuntu?

Note: I need php-fpm with my 5.2 too, so binary versions without fpm patch won't help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this Ubuntu PPA https://launchpad.net/~skettler/+archive/php

With this you can install php52 and php53, and their individual modules.

To configure with apache, use FastCGI and/or FPM. You could use mod_php for one, and fastcgi for the other, but I'd just assume use FastCGI for both of them.

Answer (score 1):

Use separate virtual machines: Place the ancient legacy software in a VM running PHP 5.2, probably on Ubuntu 10.04, while you run the modern software on PHP 5.3 on Ubuntu 12.04.

And then, of course, get rid of the ancient legacy software as quickly as you can...

Answer (score 0):

Install one whit apt-get and orther one you can install from source on orther path, or install both versions from source, is the same result.

Ispconfig use 2 or more php versions maybe you can check their tutorials, are very help ful